# VB6 RS232 not receiving full data from device using MSCOMM Controll

Tags: interface, vb6, serial-port

I have a clinical device that sends data on com port, I want to receive data from device
it also received First Frame (254) character after send ACK on ENQ
it receive **[ETB]  [CR][LF]** characters
then I again send ACK for next frame, but not receive data 
only receiving EOT char

Device Communication as per device is:

> <-[ENQ]
>
> ->[ACK]
>
> <-[STX]1H|******************************************-[ETB]21[CR][LF]
>
> ->[ACK]
>
> <-[STX]1H|******************************************-[ETX]8E[CR][LF]
>
> ->[ACK]
>
> <-[EOT]

my code is:

```
'MSComm1.Settings = "9600,n,8,1"
'MSComm1.InputLen = 1
Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
    Dim InBuff As String

    InBuff = MSComm1.Input
    if Chr$(5)=InBuff then    'ENQ received
        MSComm1.Output=Chr$(6) & VbCr
    elseif Chr$(10)=InBuff then 'LF received
        MSComm1.Output=Chr$(6) & VbCr
    else
        text1.text=text1.text & InBuff
    end if
End Sub
```

Device sending full data because 1 software comes with device which receive full data as
but I didn't receive next frame after send ACK again, 
if any one have idea what output have to send FOR next ACK, please advice me

thanks in advance

Comment: MSComm1.InputLen = 1 restricts each call to .Input to read 1 character from the buffer only; .RThreshold will determine how many characters in the rx buffer it takes to raise _oncomm, try it with 1. Set it to 0 while the event is running, use .InBufferCount to determine & deal with buffers > 1 character. Google *sysinternals portmon* for a tool to view all port tx/rx.

Comment: You will have to read the protocol spec for the device, we can't help you with that.  A guess is that the device simply considers the transaction complete so sends the End-Of-Transmission control code.  Which would require you to start another one with ENQ.  Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this...

```
MSComm1.InputLen = 1 ' for sending single character from device
MSComm1.RThreshold = 1 ' for firing events on receiving a single character

Dim InBuff As String

if MSComm1.CommEvent = comEvReceive then
do 
    InBuff = MSComm1.Input
    Loop Until MSComm1.InBufferCount < 1
```

Firstly receive all the data and after that use that in your own way.

Comment: `InBuff = InBuff & MSComm1.Input`. Otherwise InBuff will be overwritten  each loop.